# Does use of lambda in Android in Activity cause a memory leak?

Tags: android, lambda, memory-leaks, rx-java

I'm watching this presentation, and at [13:42](https://youtu.be/0XSf7sX2rCQ?t=822) they say that using lambda in the way:

[image]

```
api.getEvents()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnSubscribe(() -> loadingIndication.show())
    .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> loadingIndication.hide())
    .subscribe(...);
```

causes View to leak.

Can you explain how the leak works in this case? Does the leak appear depending on how we compile the code and what class we put the RxJava code (e.g. in Activity, in Application, in Service)?

Answer (score 3):

This causes a leak because lambdas are no different from anonymous inner classes where they will have an implicit reference to the current class where they're called, in this case it the Activity. So this piece of code actually has reference to your Activity.

```
api.getEvents()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnSubscribe(() -> loadingIndication.show())
    .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> loadingIndication.hide())
    .subscribe(events -> {}, throwable -> {});
```

I haven't had the time to checkout the video but there is a way to handle this kind of possible memory leak by using [CompositeDisposable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/disposables/CompositeDisposable.html) and adding the `Disposable` returned from the above code through `compositeDisposable.add()` and calling `compositeDisposable.clear()` on your Activity's `onDestroy()`.

Comment: it is true that the lambdas hold references to the activity, but so do the Views, even if you instantiated some static class with a reference to the View loadingIndicator, you would still have a leak

Comment: Of course, yes it does contributes to the leak. I was focused on the lambda and forgot to mention it. Thanks for pointing it out. Also if this is used in Application and Service class which unlikely to contain UI objects then the only left that can possibly cause the leak here is the lambdas.

Comment: I think the problem is not just the lambdas, if you pass an instance of a static class (call it A), and A has a reference to a Service/Activity, if you don't remove the reference to A from the stream you still have a leak. even with no lambdas. the difference with lambdas is that being the reference implicit you don't see it right away

Comment: Yes I agree but in this case though if you properly cleanup the Disposable by either manually unsubscribing or through CompositeDisposable then lambdas with its implicit reference and any explicit references to the activity/service inside it will also get cleaned up properly.

Comment: "in this case it the Activity." I don't see explicitly stated in the video that this code is in Activity.